# MissingSiteDefinition - Migrate sharepoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, migration

I migrated Sharepoint 2007 to 2010, but some sites do not open, i run the 
**Test-SPContentDatabase** command, the **MissingSiteDefinition** error is displayed for the following **TemplateId**: 75801, 75802, 75803, 75806, 75813, 75817 and 75818

So, i ran the following command: **STSADM -o enumallwebs -databasename WSS_Content** and the following result was generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<Databases>

-<Database DataSource="SQL2008\SQL2008" Name="WSS_Content" SiteCount="3">

-<Site InSiteMap="True" OwnerLogin="administrator" Id="66ae0d80-c0ad-4612-8246-9706fa16c23a">

-<Webs Count="2">
<Web Id="04aa537a-0ae2-4271-a913-96714d967b62" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/sites/administration"/>
<Web Id="0c1ce964-62d1-4ec5-9b6a-ef4d882a197c" TemplateId="75806" TemplateName="Unknown" LanguageId="1046" Url="/sites/administration/Sector1"/>

</Webs>
</Site>

-<Site InSiteMap="True" OwnerLogin="administrator" Id="20aa7454-80e5-4bc1-9bc5-a784c9d1cf17">

-<Webs Count="25">
<Web Id="39930c2d-a158-4e86-9a5f-2910f05f36e1" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/"/>
<Web Id="5ba50ae3-2075-4eee-9842-d980ef3ba45b" TemplateId="75802" TemplateName="Unknown" LanguageId="1046" Url="/contacts"/>
<Web Id="13336897-2b9f-4695-9e52-0f37194eff0e" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#1" LanguageId="1046" Url="/engineering"/>
<Web Id="c073ec4b-ec4e-4084-945d-2307479fe7f8" TemplateId="75801" TemplateName="Unknown" LanguageId="1046" Url="/engineering/gc"/>
<Web Id="cdb98f08-cfcd-4f8a-b603-7136bc08edd6" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/engineering/gcnew"/>
<Web Id="bfe5cb1e-a6a1-4850-90b7-0e72f828f613" TemplateId="75818" TemplateName="Unknown" LanguageId="1046" Url="/Conference"/>
<Web Id="93e30184-01ac-4eac-b7ee-144d73eabcd5" TemplateId="75817" TemplateName="Unknown" LanguageId="1046" Url="/checking"/>
<Web Id="f1cb918d-370a-4eb6-b4c1-c88a016a57a7" TemplateId="75813" TemplateName="Unknown" LanguageId="1046" Url="/rep/proc"/>
<Web Id="e345d76e-138f-4480-86e5-6914554651b7" TemplateId="75803" TemplateName="Unknown" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev"/>
<Web Id="b9636c3f-e1a8-4f38-86d8-71df5a16048e" TemplateId="9" TemplateName="BLOG#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/blog"/>
<Web Id="0e85e10e-a916-4d65-af97-efb6039b8635" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/Control"/>
<Web Id="370bb595-14d7-4ded-8ffd-6f439b36d259" TemplateId="9" TemplateName="BLOG#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/Control/blog"/>
<Web Id="6573ee2c-bd5f-4865-b398-db0eee3185f3" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/sctr"/>
<Web Id="207523cc-8ad0-48c5-b1ec-79b6384f8b7a" TemplateId="9" TemplateName="BLOG#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/sctr/blog"/>
<Web Id="6ad7c6cc-f968-47e7-98e7-af402b861f72" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/dim"/>
<Web Id="945e28d8-4cc6-47e7-b1cf-83e048130e16" TemplateId="9" TemplateName="BLOG#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/dim/blog"/>
<Web Id="408eaff0-4fff-4592-98f3-151c8509021c" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/dec"/>
<Web Id="9d6c895c-bcb9-4d29-a90d-88af64bff1b2" TemplateId="9" TemplateName="BLOG#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/dec/blog"/>
<Web Id="181498f0-c37b-4a8d-ba13-e450c86caa94" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/dec/sctr"/>
<Web Id="d9b7bc31-8c69-4225-88b5-2b011589639f" TemplateId="9" TemplateName="BLOG#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/dec/fiscaldocuments"/>
<Web Id="53e353f4-895e-4b51-80b2-90a252fbe05b" TemplateId="1" TemplateName="STS#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/rin"/>
<Web Id="2920f7aa-b8f9-43bb-ba17-fc41c54e1061" TemplateId="9" TemplateName="BLOG#0" LanguageId="1046" Url="/dev/rin/blog"/>

</Webs>
</Site>
</Database>
</Databases>
```

Why only sites with Templatename = 'Unknown' do not open

Example: if I try to open the URL with TemplateId="75813" following message is displayed:

[image]

If I try to open the URLs 75801 or 75802, the message is another: The Webpage can not be found

I know these templates were customized by another company sector.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the location in SharePoint 2010 server: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\XML. Check if the site template files which get MissingSiteDefinition error exist in this folder.

If not, you need to re-install the template to see if the error message occurred.

If you don't need these sites, you can delete these sites with issue, or rename the site template with a standard template ID.

Here is also a similar post you can check: [SharePoint 2013: MissingSiteDefinition Test-SPContentDatabase](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-missingsitedefinition.html)

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help.

I've been in the C: \ Program Files \ Common Files \ Microsoft Shared \ Web Server Extensions \ 14 \ TEMPLATE \ 1033 \ XML \ directory, but the templates are not there.
Could you please guide me as I do deploy?